# Visual Studio 2012 - DownloadProgressChanged not available

Tags: wcf, silverlight, frameworks, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I need to use the DownloadProgressChanged in xaml this is what i want to do DownloadProgressChanged="onSplashScreenLogoLoaded", but the type does not exists.

this works fine in VS 2008.....but not in VS 2012.
And this problem is only persist when using the silver light greater than 3.

does silver light 4 or 5 have any other option for this.

What can I do to fix the problem?